# Java Selenium stuck on 'driver.get'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code that is supposed to loop through the links from a file, but it is getting stuck after opening the first link and does nothing. I have a similar code that works fine. The only difference that I can think of is the link, but I wouldn't understand why the link would cause the  code to get stuck

Here is the initial driver setup:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "/home/ xxx /Documents/Selenium/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Here is the code that gets stuck:

```
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("unsplashPicLink.txt"));
        System.out.println("file readed");

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            linkFromFile = input.nextLine();
            // this line gets printed
             System.out.println(linkFromFile);

            // opens the web page with the picture
            driver.get(linkFromFile);
            // the following text does not get printed
            System.out.println("Show this text");

            // code here for further processing

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }
```

As you see above the code gets stuck on '**driver.get(linkFromFile)**;', showing the website and stays there.

The link that I'm pulling is as follows:

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1437650128481-845e6e35bd75?dpr=1&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1199&h=800&q=80&cs=tinysrgb
```

I have tried to add:

```
linkFromFile= linkFromFile.substring(0, linkFromFile.indexOf("?"));
linkFromFile= linkFromFile.replace("https", "http");
```

So that the link looks like:

```
http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1437650128481-845e6e35bd75
```

But it didn't make any difference. The page takes a while to load (like 5-10 sec).

I tried also to add:

```
            try {
                driver.get(linkFromFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
```

But it didn't make any difference eihter.

Any ideas why the code gets stuck? By being stuck I mean that after opening the link above nothing else happens. I would expect for the message 'Show this text' and for the next link to be open.

For example, in the same class I have the following code that loops through the links of a file and there seems to be no problem

```
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            linkFromFile = input.nextLine();

            driver.get(linkFromFile);

            try {
                List<WebElement> no = driver
                        .findElements(By.tagName("img"));

            // code here for further processing

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error " + e);
            }
        }
```

I've puzzled with a code working and a similar one not.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post how you're initializing the driver?

Comment: What do you mean get stuck?? Is there any exception?? Need to share driver initialisation code as well

Comment: Jose & Saurabh, I've edited the code adding the driver initialization and what do I mean by getting stuck, which basically is that the code doesn't progresses to finish. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I wonder if you have tried setting breakpoint on that line? What debugger says?

Comment: I don't get anything from the debugger. If I set the breakpoint on driver.get(linkFromFile); there is no information even on the variables window. If I set breakpoint beforehand I can see the variables information, like the value in linkFromFile. I don't see what can I do to get more information from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, this is how I initialise my chrome webdriver, perhaps it's an error with that? Just guessing:

```
    //I declare the following globally just under 'public  class"insernamehere"'
    private WebDriver driver;

    //I then declare the following in my @Before part
//of the test so that it initializes before every test.
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/ComputerName/Desktop/chromedriver2.23/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Let me know if this helped

Comment: Thanks MG97. I don't think there is a problem with the driver as (with exactly the same setup) it works with the other code

Comment: Okey dokes, just that I added the private WebDriver driver; declaration which mine doesn't work without, but coolio

Comment: I tried it but it didn't make any difference. Thanks for your comment anyway